# Generic entity counter routine

Tags: c#, llblgen

I have a bunch of tables which all have the same column called SessionID of type Guid, this is the ID of the session the entities were created in. I am trying to write a generic class that will count the entities for specific session and specific entity type. Has anyone done something like that with LLBLGen?

```
public class EntityCounterControl<T> where T : EntityBase2, IEntity2
{       
    public int CountEntities(Guid sessionID)
    {
        //How can I count the entities for type T?

    }
};
```

Comment: do you have entitycollection in-memory? a single collection or multiple collections could have entities for the given sessionID?

Comment: We have a similar case, but doing it with a view that connects all tables with UNION. Think that is more elegant, than doing it with LLBLGen ... You can than query the view and specify the session

Comment: I don't have a collection in memory, also multiple collections/tables can  have entities for the same SessionID

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use generics? You can create an interface that defines the SessionId property and have your entities implement it.

Comment: That's what I am doing at the moment, but I just find that I am writing very similar code for each entity